Get emacs to work with a local site-lisp directory
I must install some programs into a local directory, ~/local/.
Some programs create emacs packages in ~/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/ and I would like emacs to autoload them.
A flawed way to load maxima, for example, is to add the following lines to init.el:
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/local/share/emacs/site-lisp"))
(require 'maxima)

This is bad because I don't want to load the maxima package unless I need it, and I don't want to manually maintain a list of packages from ~/local.
There seems to be a way of doing this automatically but I haven't been able to understand existing answers. Can anyone explain how to do this?

How did you install maxima? Usually a maxima-autoloads.el is installed (or produced), so you can (require 'maxima-autoloads) - that will load the (tiny) autoloads which will sit there patiently until you invoke one, which will then autoload the package.

If a maxima-autoloads.el is not part of the installation, you should be able to produce one by opening maxima.el and using loaddefs-generate.

But if you install it from MELPA, the package system should take care of these things (I think).

I was wondering something similar. You’ll need to use loaddefs-generate. Put this in your init.el:
(let ((site-lisp (expand-file-name "~/local/share/emacs/site-lisp"))
      (autoloads-file (expand-file-name "site-lisp-autoloads.el"
                                        user-emacs-directory)))
  (loaddefs-generate site-lisp autoloads-file)
  (load autoloads-file))

(Feel free to change the value of autoloads-file, that just seemed like a sensible place to me for the autoloads file to end up.)
Or, if you’re like me and there are subdirectories in your site-lisp folder, use this instead:
(let* ((site-lisp (expand-file-name "~/local/share/emacs/site-lisp"))
       (subdirectories
        (cl-loop for file in (directory-files-recursively site-lisp "" t)
                 if (file-directory-p file)
                 collect file))
       (directories (nconc (list site-lisp) subdirectories))
       (autoloads-file (expand-file-name "site-lisp-autoloads.el"
                                         user-emacs-directory)))
  (loaddefs-generate directories autoloads-file)
  (load autoloads-file))

(It’s important that you call loaddefs-generate only once, here, with the first argument being the full list of directories you want scanned for autoloads; when loaddefs-generate begins its work, it makes note of the file-modified time of the output file, and then only adds new definitions to the output file if the file being scanned is “newer” than the output file. So if you run loaddefs-generate for each directory in turn, with the same output file, it’ll update it once, then note that the output file is newer than anything it’s scanning, and you’ll only get one directory’s autoloads saved into the output file. That caused me some trouble while making this answer!)
